# Pci device file identifier?

Tags: linux, hard-disk, devices, pci

As regards disk devices, Linux systems represent them through a `/dev/` file. `/dev/sda` is a hard drive, and so on.

Is there also a file representing a PCI device, for example a graphic card? If not, how can the system interface with them?